# In GAE Java 11, how do I enqueue a task to run in the same subdomain of current code?

Tags: google-app-engine

My logs show a 404 error when I run this code:

```
String queuePath = QueueName.of( PROJECT_ID, LOCATION, QUEUE_NAME ).toString( );

Task.Builder taskBuilder = Task.newBuilder( )

                .setAppEngineHttpRequest(

                    AppEngineHttpRequest.newBuilder( )
                        .setRelativeUri( relativeUri )
                        .setHttpMethod( HttpMethod.GET )
                        .build( )

                );

Task task = client.createTask( queuePath, taskBuilder.build( ) );
```

The logs seem to show the request is going to my main domain, not my subdomain that this code is running in.

What am I missing?

2023-01-05 Update:

I had to resort to the generic approach as seen here.

```
           Task.Builder taskBuilder = Task.newBuilder( )

                .setHttpRequest(

                    HttpRequest.newBuilder( )
                        .setUrl( fullUri )
                        .setHttpMethod( HttpMethod.GET )
                        .build( )

                );
```

Comment: Updated the code as per your requirement and I have tested it with my domain as well it is working as intended let me know if any error occurs for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed giving the subdomain to the cloud run Task queues.

Lets say, if your subdomain is `subdomain.example.com` and you want to enqueue a task to run at `/task`, you will set the relative URI to `/task`.

To resolve your problem I have modified your code with giving you `/subdomain` as subdomain:

```
String hostname = "api.mydomain.com";
String relativeUri = "/servlet-path";

String queuePath = QueueName.of( PROJECT_ID, LOCATION, QUEUE_NAME ).toString( );

Task.Builder taskBuilder = Task.newBuilder()
    .setAppEngineHttpRequest(
        AppEngineHttpRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setRelativeUri(relativeUri)
                            .setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                            .setHost(hostname)
                            .build()
     );

Task task = client.createTask( queuePath, taskBuilder.build());
```

Alternatively you can add subdomain in google cloud console by following this

```
Console -> App Engine -> Settings -> Custom Domains -> Add a Custom Domain
```

as shown in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55593853/20239914)

For Information about this topic you can go through this [documentations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024884/20239914) and for official reference you can go to [here](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-tasks/latest/com.google.cloud.tasks.v2beta3.AppEngineHttpRequest.Builder#com_google_cloud_tasks_v2beta3_AppEngineHttpRequest_Builder_setRelativeUri_java_lang_String_)

Comment: This code is running in api.mydomain.com. I am trying to enqueue a servlet at api.mydomain.com/servlet-path. It ends up making a request to www.mydomain.com/servlet-path. Making a request to www.mydomain.com/api/servlet-path does not work.

Comment: @BruceWilcox Updated the code as per your requirement and I have tested it with my domain as well it is working as intended let me know if any error occurs for you

Comment: The new .setHost() method makes sense. I'll give that a try.